# Could not update ICEAuthority file /home/neha/.ICEAuthority

Tags: linux, operating-system

Hi I am getting `Could not update ICEAuthority file /home/neha/.ICEAuthority` issue when I am loging from my account on Ubantu 12.4.

Please help me

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/55568/could-not-update-iceauthority-file-after-login-independent-of-gnome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved it by my own using

```
ctrl+alt+F1
```

It will ask for user/password

then

```
 rm .ICEauthority
```

then restart system and it worked for me.

I got help from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1841457&p=11235569#post11235569)

Really thanks to this link

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After reading many posts about this error, I have come to the conclusion that it has to do with creating files and directories sometimes as root and sometimes as the user. As a result the ICEauthority is so garbled that it convinces itself it is corrupt. This is how i fixed it:

Boot to login screen:

```
ctl+alt+f1
```

Login with username and password:
    $ su

Root password

```
# sudo chown -R username:groupname /home/username
```

This should reset all the permissions in the users home folder to all match

```
alt+f7
```

Try broken username and password; it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Do not remove this file !, all you have to do it change the ownership of your home directory and add the correct permissions !